# C# code to Import Excel data in to SQL server 2008

Tags: c#

My question which is the  best approach to import the data from Excel to SQL server 2008. It has lots of check like duplicates check etc.,

I would say we have

1.Import Export wizard
2.SSIS package
3.Create a .NET Console App  with inline query
4.Create a .NET console app with stored proc because it has lots of checking conditions.

Which is the best approach?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a one time import or a custom app that needs to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can debate over option 2 and 4. The choice will mainly depend on if the job requires to run periodically. If yes - I will go ahead with SSIS package otherwise I will go ahead with .NET console app with the logic to be in a SP.

Quick suggestions - Implement logging for failed rows. So that you can run a job to retry.

Comment: If it is one time data import I can goahead for choice 4 right

Comment: I have argued with my collegue,she/he insisted me to go for .NET console app with inline code but I told it has lot off logic and checks are there it is better to go with Stored proc and .NET console app or SSIS.Is this argument correct or am I wrong Please tell me.Please tell me the Proof od concept which is the best approach

Comment: Thats correct. Stored Proc will give you performance benefit as opposed to inline query. I am not sure about the checks etc.. you are referring to... however you can take you call to implement them either in .net code or SQL based on their complexity. SQL SP would be best suited to do the core DB activities like Insert/UPdate/Delete etc.. Hope this clarifies...

Comment: Everybody has their own approach,As per the best approach is write a .NET console application and SP right.If they did not care about the performance issue and say you have to develop only in .NET with inline code.Do you think you will accept it even he is your Senior?else you will make him understand.If the requirements are not clear and incomplete.Is it possible for you to assume and import.

Comment: If it is just about "do it now".. go ahead and implement with inline sql.. Obviously no body is going to hang you for that..